# What is the best method to capture latex output for questions and answers?

Tags: support, answers, questions, formatting, best-practice

I have seen questions and answers posting output from latex that appear to blend in well with the site. In looking at the html/css underlying these posts, it appears that all that is required is to block quote the image and supply an image with a transparent background. When I produce a pdf and clip a portion of the screen, the resulting image has a white background and looks like this:

> [image: romanurl]

rather than, like this (using a transparent background image):

> [image: anotherromanurl]

What is the best way to capture latex output for use in questions/answers and is it best practice to block quote it?

Comment: Many of them convert to png directly which supports alpha and transparency. For block quote a single `>` is enough per paragraph.

Comment: From a semantic point of view, you shouldn't do this, since you're not quoting anyone.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *need* to do this, since one can display transparency as an overlay against another background as well.

This is purely up to personal preference.

I peruse the StackExchange network through Google Chrome. This allows me to copy-and-paste images directly via the image insertion capability (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>); no need for saving the image and uploading it - it's fast. However, this loses the capability to insert images that "blend in nicely".

Answer (score 1):

It took a little digging, but this approach works...

First, there needs to be some latex (save as somefile.tex):

```
\documentclass[12pt, preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\Huge http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function\_(mathematics)

\end{document}
```

Next, turn the latex into a pdf:

`pdflatex somefile.tex`

Then convert the pdf to png:

`convert -density 300 somefile.pdf -quality 90 somefile.png`

And finally, create a block quote with the resulting png:

> [image: nicelookinglatex]

It sure looks better than the alternative:

> [image: notnicelookinglatex]